# React - Ant Design Form-Item name props broke Select value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-functional-component

I m using antD and if I use **select** component inside of form item and if this form item has **name** as props I can not set value to my select component while page was rendering.

Just make it clear what I tried to say, I prepared a example and you can copy and paste it to the codesandbox or etc.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
    import './index.css';
    import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from 'antd';
    const { Option } = Select;
    
    
    export const Demo =()=> {
      let formRef = React.createRef();
        return (
          <Form ref={formRef} name="control-ref">   
            <Form.Item 
              label="Gender"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Select value="male">
                <Option value="male">male</Option>
                <Option value="female">female</Option>
                <Option value="other">other</Option>
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>       
          </Form>
        );
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

If you try to give name props to form item in this example your select component's initial value will not
be set.
More over using hooks not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question, but as far as I do, I'll try to help.

You can try `useRef`.

`import React,{useRef, useEffect} from 'react';`

```
 export const Demo =()=> {
     var formRef = useRef();

      useEffect(() => {
      formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
     select:"male"
     })
  });
      
    <Form ref={formRef} name="control-ref">   
                <Form.Item 
                  label="Gender"
                   name="select"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Select>
                    <Option value="male">male</Option>
                    <Option value="female">female</Option>
                    <Option value="other">other</Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>       
    </Form>
);}
```

Do not forget to give the `name` of the relevant `Form.Item`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but what if I have two select component in this Form... In this case it will set all select component with male in this Form component

Comment: Isn't it worth taking the other select element into the `Form.Item` scope and changing the `name`?

Comment: It may worth.. On the other hand I found solution for my second question... Mr Gucal thank you so much for all your help You are a life saver <3 :)